# Error:$ajax is not defined in asp.net

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax

while passing values to my method I am facing following error:

> Error Uncaught ReferenceError: $ajax is not defined

Here is my code:

```
$ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'UserWebService.asmx/addDetails',
    data: "{'name':'" + name + "'}",
    contentType: "application/json; charset-utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (response) {
        var result = response.d;
        alert(result);
    },
    failure: function (msg) {
        alert(msg);
    }
});
```

I hope some one can provide an answer to my problem.

Thanks in advance

Comment: $.ajax not $ajax, not sure if thats a typo or not.

Comment: I have added the  jquery-1.4.3.min.js library file

Comment: Did you add '<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">' up  to ajax code? and also you should add javacsript library like jquery-1.9.2.min.js or something like that

Comment: i have added in head part of page

Answer (score 7):

Looks like you're using jQuery - it should probably be

```
$.ajax(...
```

Comment: Please provide full code in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
jQuery.ajax({ 
    type: "POST",
    url: 'UserWebService.asmx/addDetails',
    data: "{'name':'" + name + "'}",
    contentType: "application/json; charset-utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    async: false,
    success: function (response) {
        var result = response.d;
        alert(result);
    },
    failure: function (msg) {
        alert(msg);
    }
});
```